# How to do programmatic configuration for log4j2 RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j2 programmatically without a configuration file, but configuring it in code. I'm trying to use the log4j2 `RollingFileAppender` to save the last 10 log files. I tried limiting the file size using the `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy`. The size limitation works but it doesn't create old log files and just keeps deleting and writing to the one original log file.

```
public static void configLog() {
        String dir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "test\\";
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config).withPattern(PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN).build();
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy policy = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("1KB");
        DefaultRolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.createStrategy("10", "0", null, null, config);
        RollingFileManager fileManager = RollingFileManager.getFileManager(dir + "log\\test.log", dir + "log\\test-%i.log", false, false, policy, strategy, null, layout, 128);
        policy.initialize(fileManager);
        RollingFileAppender appender = RollingFileAppender.createAppender(dir + "log\\test.log", dir + "log\\test-%i.log",
                "false", "File", "false", "128", "true", policy, strategy, layout, (Filter) null, "false", "false", (String) null, config);
        appender.start();
        config.addAppender(appender);
        AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", Level.INFO, null);
        AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] { ref };
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("true", Level.INFO, LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME, "true",
                refs, null, config, null);
        loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, Level.INFO, null);
        config.addLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME, loggerConfig);
        ctx.updateLoggers();
    }
```

I didn't manage to find a lot of examples configuring the logging with java but i need to for my application. The example from where I took most of the code is here http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html (the second code part).

Why doesn't it create/save old log files?

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is an old question others may find it useful, i believe it to be because

```
RollingFileAppender.createAppender(dir + "log\\test.log", dir + "log\\test-%i.log",
            "false", "File", "false", "128", "true", policy, strategy, layout, (Filter) null, "false", "false", (String) null, config);
```

should be

```
RollingFileAppender.createAppender(dir + "log\\test.log", dir + "log\\test-%i.log",
            "true", "File", "false", "128", "true", policy, strategy, layout, (Filter) null, "false", "false", (String) null, config);
```

The third argument is the append option
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/RollingFileAppender.html

Comment: Proof that the Log4j team don't care about ease of programmatic initialization (which I prefer over XML which has no compile-time safety: it just doesn't log at runtime and often the failure is silent).

Comment: They have since added builders which should make it quite a bit easier.Unfortunately when i upgraded some time back that was not available for me and it was quite difficult to get the programmatic config right.

Comment: I was just playing with the newer version and the fact that it’s so string-based defeats half my purpose - to have the help of the compiler in setting up values correctly (you just find out it just doesn’t work at runtime). It’s basically semi-weakly typed, which is barely any better than just xml inside java code. And Logback is so intertwined with slf4j that if another dependency imports log4j, you can’t get it to use logback. #logginghell